# How to display value in a column as links using react-bootstrap table-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-table, react-table

Im using React Table (react bootstrap table-2) to display a table in a page and populate it with data called from an database API. I want to make the values displayed in one of the columns as links( hrefs). This particular column contains only URLs. How to implement this in react bootstrap table-2 ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import * as ReactBootstrap from "react-bootstrap";
import filterFactory, { textFilter } from "react-bootstrap-table2-filter";
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";

const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { SearchBar } = Search;

  const getListData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/results");
      console.log(data);
      setList(data.data);
      setLoading(true);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  const columns = [
    { dataField: "dept_name", text: "DepartMent" },
    { dataField: "Tr_type", text: "Transmission Type", sort: true },
    { dataField: "E_type", text: "Entry Type", sort: true },
    { dataField: "Msg_des", text: "Message Description", sort: true },
    { dataField: "cr_date", text: "Created Date", sort: true },
    { dataField: "ch", text: "Channel", sort: true },
    { dataField: "Del", text: "Delivered", sort: true },
    { dataField: "fl", text: "Failed", sort: true },
    { dataField: "report", text: "Show Detailed Report" },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    getListData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        <ToolkitProvider keyField="name" data={list} columns={columns} search>
          {(props) => (
            <div>
              <div className="serSec">
                <h3 className="hdrOne">Search:</h3>
                <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
              </div>

              <div class="table-responsive">
                  
                <BootstrapTable
                  {...props.baseProps}
                  filter={filterFactory()}
                  pagination={paginationFactory()}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </ToolkitProvider>
      ) : (
        <ReactBootstrap.Spinner animation="border" />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This what I tried :

```
{
datafield : "report",
text : "Show report",
accessor : "link",
Cell : (e) => <a href={e.value}> {e.value} </a>
},
```

I'm not getting any error with the above workaround though the value "show report" is displayed as text as of now. Can anyone provide any workaround for the same or is there any other method to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I loop up the [docs](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Work%20on%20Columns&selectedStory=Dummy%20Column&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel). The `formatter` may help you.

```
      {
        dataField: 'report',
        text: 'Show report',
        formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex, extraData) => (
          <div>
            <a href={row.value}> {row.value} </a>
          </div>
        )
      },
```